# How to bind for MVVM when control is not part of the visual tree

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I am using the `Extended Tool` Kit by `XCeed`. I'm finding I can not bind particulary easy (or at all) to their controls. I was having to use the code behind to reference controls by their `x:Name`

I'm now using a `MVVM` pattern and so it no longer is an option.

My reading *suggests* the fault is due to their control is not part of the visual tree although I don't know how I can test this.

The problem is, with using their ToggleSwitch control, which I want to bind to my ViewModel. The ViewModel implements INPC and binding for my combo boxes, textboxes etc all binds as expected.

```
<xctk:ToggleSwitch HorizontalAlignment="Left" IsChecked="{Binding IsContinue}" />
```

And my ViewModel

```
private bool _IsContinue;
public bool IsContinue
{
    get { return this._IsContinue; }
    set
    {
        if (this._IsContinue== value)
            return;

        this._IsContinue= value;
        OnPropertyChanged("IsContinue");
    }
}
```

Since this binding does not work (meaning regardless of whether I "check" the toggle switch or not, the result is always false) I am lost as to how I can get the binding to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've setup a "one-way binding": The control will get its value from the viewmodel, but can not set it back to the viewmodel.

Setup the binding like

`IsChecked="{Binding IsContinue, Mode = TwoWay}"`

and it should work.

Comment: This works, will mark it as answer 8 mins. Do you know why do I not need to set up Mode = TwoWay with the normal checkbox? Is it as simple as it's 'built in' to the CheckBox alreade?

Comment: You'll need to do that with a regular Checkbox too. Just checked it in a simple project, and it won't work without. If it does, something else is going on.

Comment: hmmmmm -I will need to investigate and learn more about the bindings. Any way, thank you for taking the time to help! It is very much appreciated